# Parsing Xml file in java to fetch the element matching given tag value

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have an xml as follow:

```
<root>

<outer>
<name>abc</name>
<age>20</age>
</outer>

<outer>
<name>def</name>
<age>30</age>
</outer>

<outer>
<name>ghi</name>
<age>40</age>
</outer>


</root>
```

I want to fetch the value of age tag for a given value of name tag?

One way is that I can prepare a map of name to age by parsing this xml using Document interface.

But is there any api that I can just call for Document interface in which I can say fetch element where  name is say,ghi, and then i can iterate all atributes to get age attribute or any other simple way to get age where name value is,say ghi?

Comment: I'm not familiar with java XML parsing, but should be trivial with XPath

Comment: I have xml available in org.w3c.dom.Document object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is a very expressive API that can be used to select the elements.

```
/root/outer[name = "ghi"]/age
```

This article https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath provides a pretty good overview and explanation of how to apply an XPath in Java.

Adjusting one of their code samples for your XPath:

```
String name = "ghe";

DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(this.getFile());
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String expression = "/root/outer[name=" + "'" + name + "'" + "]/age";
node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out java does come with an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) evaluator in the [`javax.xml.xpath` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html), which makes this trivial:

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String name = "ghi";
        // XPath expression to find an outer tag with a given name tag
        // and return its age tag
        String expression = String.format("/root/outer[name='%s']/age", name);
        
        // Parse an XML document
        DocumentBuilder builder
            = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new File("example.xml"));

        // Get an XPath object and evaluate the expression
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        int age = xpath.evaluateExpression(expression, document, Integer.class);

        System.out.println(name + " is " + age + " years old");       
    }
}
```

Example use:

```sh
$ java Demo.java
ghi is 40 years old
```

Comment: thanks,i will try and update

Comment: both solutions worked fine